# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/auth/ktx/AuthKt

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using this bom version:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
```

I receive those error when I do Firebase.auth()

Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Did you add the proper import? If yes, what is the import you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Check parameter **multidex**

Example:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

implementation with

```
 implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I already have those code but it doesn't work

Comment: @Sbirulinu can you change the library to this version ?

**com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0**
in your case it needs to be lowered.


Also tell me if you have this library connected?
**'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$version'**
if so, then it should be removed.

Comment: so auth error not it works with 32.0.0 version...while now I have another error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/database/ktx/DatabaseKt

Comment: This error says that you have installed versions of firebase libraries that conflict with each other. You need to check all library versions and Kotlin version as well as all dependencies